# Tfoot width misaligned when fixed to bottom in a responsive table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix the tfoot to the bottom of the page with it being as responsive as the rows of the table.

My code: https://codepen.io/adu8/pen/MWWXqGY

The problem I face now is once I add the class="fixed-bottom" to the tr of tfoot, it goes to bottom and gets misaligned.
I tried fixing it with having a workaround by adding this css:

```
tfoot td {
display: inline-block;
width: calc((100%/8) - 10px);
}
```

As in this codepen: https://codepen.io/adu8/pen/dyyKqOv. However, it's still not able to be as responsive.

I would appreciate if someone helps fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this CSS

```css
body {
  background-color: midnightblue;
  color: white;
}

table {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

thead, tr, tfoot {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: midnightblue;
}

.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover > th {
    /*background-color: #06765d;*/
    background-color: #009999;
}

.table td {
    padding: 0.05rem;
    margin: 0px;
}

.fixed-bottom {
    width: 100%;
}
table tr {
  display: flex; display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
tr th,
tr td {
    width: calc(100% / 8);
}
tr th:first-child,
tr td:first-child {
    width: 22%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
}
```